# I want to reshape 2D array into 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to reshape 2D array into 3D array.I wrote codes,

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    i = np.reshape(i,(2,2,2))
    print(i)
```

i variable has even number's length array like `[["100","150","2","4"],["140","120","3","5"]]` or

```
[[“1”,”5”,”6”,”2”],[“4”,”2”,”3”,”7”],[“7”,”5”,”6”,”6”],[“9”,”1”,”8”,”3”],[“3”,”4”,”5”,”6”],[“7”,”8”,”9”,”2”],,[“1”,”5”,”2”,”8”],[“6”,”7”,”2”,”1”],[“9”,”3”,”1”,”2”],[“6”,”8”,”3”,”3”]]
```

The length is >= 6.
When I run this codes,ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 148 into shape (2,2,2) error happens.
My ideal output is

```
[[['100', '150'], ['2', '4']], [['140', '120'], ['3', '5']]] or [[[“1”,”5”],[”6”,”2”]],[[“4”,”2”],[”3”,”7”]],[[“7”,”5”],[”6”,”6”]],[[“9”,”1”],[”8”,”3”]],[[“3”,”4”],[”5”,”6”]],[[“7”,”8”],[”9”,”2”]],[[“1”,”5”],[”2”,”8”]],[[“6”,”7”],[”2”,”1”]],[[“9”,”3”],[[”1”,”2”]],[[“6”,”8”],[”3”,”3”]]]
```

I rewrote the codes`y = [[x[:2], x[2:]] for x in i]` but output is not my ideal one.What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: What is the dimension of your 2D array, how many elements are there? row? and column ?

Comment: @Spandy array has 2 set of 4 elements like ["100","150","2","4"].Total element is several number of 2 set of 4 elements.

Comment: @Spandy So it is not fixed the number of length.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are missing the meaning of reshaping. Let say your origin array has shape (A, B) and you want to reshape it to shape (M, N, O), you have to make sure that A * B = M * N * O. Obviously 148 != 2 * 2 * 2, right?

In your case, you want to reshape an array of shape (N, 4) to an array of shape (N, 2, 2). You can do like below:

```
x = np.reshape(y, (-1, 2, 2))
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: To make it more clear, you can always set the unknown dimension to -1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop to reshape the way you want to, just use `arr.reshape((-1,2,2))`

```
In [3]: x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(2,4))

In [4]: x
Out[4]:
array([[1, 1, 2, 5],
       [8, 8, 0, 5]])

In [5]: x.reshape((-1,2,2))
Out[5]:
array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 5]],

       [[8, 8],
        [0, 5]]])
```

This approach will work for both of your arrays.  The `-1` as the first argument means numpy will infer the value of the unknown dimension.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [76]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(3,8)
In [77]: for i in range(len(arr)):
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:     i = np.reshape(i, (2,2,2))
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:     
0
....

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

`len(arr)` is 3, so `range(3)` produces values, 0,1,2.  You can't reshape the number `0`.

Or did you mean to reshape `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, etc?

```
In [79]: for i in arr:
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:     i = np.reshape(i, (2,2,2))
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:     
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[[[0 1]
  [2 3]]

 [[4 5]
  [6 7]]]
[ 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
[[[ 8  9]
  [10 11]]

 [[12 13]
  [14 15]]]
[16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
[[[16 17]
  [18 19]]

 [[20 21]
  [22 23]]]
```

That works - sort of.  The prints look ok, but `arr` itself does not get changed:

```
In [80]: arr
Out[80]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

That's because `i` is the iteration variable.  Assigning a new value to it does not change the original object.  If that's confusing, you need to review basic Python iteration.

Or we could iterate the range, and use it as an index:

```
In [81]: for i in range(len(arr)):
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:     x = np.reshape(arr[i], (2,2,2))
    ...:     print(x)
    ...:     arr[i] = x
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...:     
0
[[[0 1]
  [2 3]]

 [[4 5]
  [6 7]]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-5f0985cb2277> in <module>()
      3     x = np.reshape(arr[i], (2,2,2))
      4     print(x)
----> 5     arr[i] = x
      6 
      7 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2,2) into shape (8)
```

The reshape works, but you can't put a (2,2,2) array back into a slot of shape (8,).  The number of elements is right, but the shape isn't.

In other words, you can't reshape an array piecemeal.  You have to reshape the whole thing.  (If `arr` was a list of lists, this kind of piecemeal reshaping would work.)

```
In [82]: np.reshape(arr, (3,2,2,2))
Out[82]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15]]],


       [[[16, 17],
         [18, 19]],

        [[20, 21],
         [22, 23]]]])
```